# Iterator related error when I executed the WordCount example using Spark in Java 1.8

Tags: java, apache-spark

When I copied and pasted the WordCount example that is in the apache spark homepage, I got the following error. (I used the Java 1.8 for lambda expression)

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> countsk = input.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(" ")).iterator())  //where error occurred.
                .mapToPair(x -> new Tuple2<>(x, 1))
                .reduceByKey((x, y) -> x + y);

Error message : no instances of type variable(s) U exist so that iterator<String> conforms to Iterable<U>.
```

After got this error message, I fixed the code as below and it did work well.

```
 JavaRDD<String> words = input.flatMap(str -> Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")));
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(str -> new Tuple2<>(str, 1));
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);
```

However, It is a little bit strange to me because I just copied and pasted the code that is provided by apache spark. Why I got such an error and how to resolve above issue?

I think that `flatMap` returns the iterator type. From this point of view, I think that the first code which gave the error message is more accurate code than the below one. I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Which Spark version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact in using flatMap and flatMapToPair the output differs according to the spark version is being used:

1. In spark version 2 which needs you send back an iterator on the collection
2. Instead of the collection which is used in spark under the version 2.

   So, your spark version may be 1.6 and this problem raises because of it.